# Java 16 jre version problem when converting jar to exe

Tags: java, jar, exe

I am currently working on the final touches for my SoundSphere program
and unfortinately I can not seem to get the jar file to convert to a exe file with launch4j due to this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I understand it has to do with the fact that I coded this program in java 16 with fx and it can only recognize up to version 8 with the jre.

My question is how would I go about fixing this / where can I get a jre for java 16 ?

Thank you for your time and any help

Thomas Gustafson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have it already get https://adoptopenjdk.net/

If you do, i guess that you then already have *jre16* as it should be part of *jdk16*.
It seems that you have older *jre* installed and set as default *jre*.
You need to change PATH in your environment variables to see *java* executable from *jdk16* prior to *jre8*.

OR

You could use some JRE of 16 that has installer: https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk16&jvmVariant=hotspot

For example **windows x64 jre16 msi installer**: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk16-binaries/releases/download/jdk-16.0.1%2B9/OpenJDK16U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_16.0.1_9.msi